# AHO Channel Extra: Digimon Tri Chapter 3 is Now Streaming!

Tags: discussion, events

Come watch anime with us on the weekends!

For this weekend and next, we're streaming the [third chapter](http://www.crunchyroll.com/anime-news/2016/09/22-1/crunchyroll-adds-digimon-adventure-tri-chapter-3-confession-on-923) of *Digimon Tri* thru Crunchyroll. All users, new and old, are welcome to participate via [rabb.it](http://www.rabb.it/Krazer).

All sessions will be by request via [our main chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-) or our [Discord channel](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3927/introducing-the-aho-channel-the-community-discord-channel-of-this-stack-exchange). A screening will start once there are at least two users are ready to watch. Set up a time and we'll get watching. To start a request you must ping me via chat or Discord.

Multiple sessions will be running all weekend, so if you miss one viewing, you can still catch another. Bring as many friends, snacks and drinks for some Digimon battles. If you're not satiated afterward there will also be a free watch session for recommended anime.

You will need at least a basic DSL connection to be able to properly enjoy the session.